# Add Label to all nodes in arbitrary cipher query

Tags: python, neo4j, cypher

I am writing a web app with a single neo4j database as the datastore. Different users have their own separate charts. I have checked other documentation and found that neo4j doesn't have a concept of schema and instead it is suggested that labels are used against every node to indicate which graph it belongs to.

I am writing a middleware for the web app in Python which deals with user logins and sends queries onwards to the database. I am building a webservice in this middleware which accepts a cipher query string and returns the query result. Before it forwards the query string on to the database it needs to alter it, adding a label depending on the logged in user.

I need to build a function as follows:

```
def query_for_user(origional_query, users_label):
  return XXX
```

My first idea on how to do this is to use string processing based on information here: https://neo4j.com/docs/getting-started/current/cypher-intro/patterns/
Every node in a query is surrounded by brackets so I could replace every part of the query inside brackets with a new version. The brackets always seem to start with a node identifier so I could read past this and add the required label. Seems like it would work but would be error prone and brittle because I don't know all the features of cpher.

Does anyone know of a more elegant way of achieving my goal? Is there a cypher parser somewhere that I could use instead of string manipulation?

Answer (score 0):

Neo4j labels are *not* meant to be used to separate nodes into different "graphs".

A label is meant to be used as a node "type". For example, "Person" would be an example of a typical label, but having a huge number of labels like "User049274658188" or "Graph93458428834" would not be good practice.

As appropriate, nodes should have a "type"-like label, and can include a property (say, `id`) whose value is a unique identifier. Your queries can then start by matching a specific label/id combination in order to indicate which "graph" you want to work on. All other nodes in that "graph" would be linked to that start node via relationship paths.

And typically one would generate Cypher from raw data, not Cypher templates. However, if you really want to use Cypher templating, the templates could just contain Cypher [parameters](https://neo4j.com/docs/cypher-manual/current/syntax/parameters/), as in:

```
MATCH (p:Person)-[:LIVES_AT]->(a:Address) WHERE p.id = $personId RETURN p, a;
```

Your client code will just need to provide the parameter values when invoking the query.